# Proper (safe) use of `static_cast`

Tags: c++, casting

I'm using this pattern:

```
struct Base {
    int i;
};

struct Derived: Base {
    int j;
};

class A {
  public:
    A(Base* b): _b(b) { }
    virtual int get_int() { return _b->i; }
  protected:
    Base* const _b;
};

class B: public A {
  public:
    B(Derived* d): A(d) { }
    int get_int() { return static_cast<Derived* const>(_b)->j; }
};
```

This use of `static_cast` looks safe to me, as the `const` prevents a class deriving from `B` from assigning a `Base*` to `_b`. Am I overlooking something, i.e., is there a chance of undefined behaviour lurking here? Is there a better or more idiomatic way to achieve the same effect?

I can see a couple alternatives:

- Use `dynamic_cast`: no chance of undefined behaviour, but I want to compile without RTTI
- Make `i` and `j` members of `A` and `B`: leads to code duplication if other hierarchies use `Base` and `Derived`

Comment: Whell there is a chance of UB, if `_b` is of type `Base`. `static_cast` checks only for type compatibility it does not check if the instance is actually of type `Derived`. One way to avoid `dynamic_cast` is to manually keep track the type of the instance class. In this case you need to add a private member in Base indicating which type the class is. Or you can create a virtual function `enum Types{ BaseClass, DerivedClass }; virtual Types getType(){return BaseClass; or return DerivedClass; depending on where you implement it}`

Comment: The `const` is not what makes this code work. It is the fact that the `B` constructor does not allow anything other than a `Derived` or descendant to be assigned to `_b`.  However, there is one case you are not handling - if `B` is constructed with a NULL `Derived*`, so `_b` is NULL when accessed by `get_int()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The null issue is separate (it's there even if we're only working with `A` and `Base`), and you're correct that I've overlooked it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau The `const` is there in case somebody (user) wants to make a class `C` deriving from `B` and for whatever reason decides to assign to `_b` a pointer of type `Base*` in one of its methods.

Comment: @Raxvan I think I've set it up so that there's no chance of `*_b` being of type `Base` when `B::get_int` is called.

Comment: The risk is that the pattern is extraordinarily confusing.  Off the top of my head, I can't see a situation where something like that is useful.  I'm assuming that your example is a simplified version of the real but in that example the struct is so simple that I'm not sure why you don't just make an accessor in the base class, and I'm even more confused about why you are dealing with pointers at all.

Comment: @shawn1874 Imagine `A` and `Base` are 3rd-party classes which cannot be modified and `Base` has a lot of virtual functions and child classes and is used polymorphically all over the place. The members `i` and `j` are just standing in for "something which `Derived` has but `Base` does not".